# How to take this derivative

Tags: derivatives, summation

My question is straightforward: I need to evaluate an expression of the form

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\sum_{k=0}^{t}\varphi(k,t)
$$

How is this done, usually?

Comment: How do you define your summation with non-integer endpoint?

Comment: I'm certain that you can make something like that meaningful so long as you withhold the same type of disbelief as when you compute (d/dx)^(1.1) etc. Fractional versions of initially discrete operations are everywhere...!

Comment: Well you may want to provide a definition if you use non-standard notation.

Answer (score 0):

If instead of a sum you had an integral, things make a little more sense. Suppose
$$
I(t)=\int_0^t\phi(s,t)\ ds.
$$
To evaluate $I'(t)$, we could do the following:
$$
\begin{align*}
I(t)&=\int_0^{\infty}\chi_{[0,t]}(s)\phi(s,t)\ ds\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\chi_{[s,\infty]}(t)\phi(s,t)\ ds\\
\end{align*}
$$
Here $\chi$ denotes the characteristic function of a set. Assuming the integrand is sufficiently regular (i.e. a uniform $L^1$ bound local in $t$), we may differentiate under the integral sign to obtain
$$
\begin{align*}
I'(t)&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{d}{dt}\left(\chi_{[s,\infty]}(t)\phi(s,t)\right)\ ds\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\chi_{[s,\infty]}(t)\phi_t(s,t)+\delta(t-s)\phi(s,t)\ ds\\
&= \phi(t,t)+\int_0^t\phi_t(s,t)\ ds.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Sure, I've arrived at this too using Leibniz's Integral rule, but I really need the version for a summation. It's clearly not possible all the time (meaning some $\varphi(n,k)$ will make our lives difficult), but perhaps there is a way to evaluate what I originally wrote whenever it is.

Comment: I might be able to turn the sum into an integral using the Dirac comb and do it your way...?

Comment: Maybe write down the application you have in mind. As it stands your original question isn't properly defined.

Comment: If $\Xi(x)$ is the Dirac comb then $\sum_{k=0}^{x}f(x,k) = \int_0^xf(x,t)\Xi(t)dt$ appears to hold for positive integers x. So then proceeding as we said (taking the derivative of right side) yields $f(x,x)\Xi(x) + \int_0^x\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}\Xi(t)dt$, which seems shady at best but might have meaning in some limits...although a quick check with a simple sum tells me that this doesn't work for non-integer x and the two functions (RHS and LHS of first eqn. of this comment) grow differently, so maybe I need to modify my integrand or find a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that seems to work, actually, but that I have not rigorously proven does so.

Make the following construction:

$$
\phi(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n\varphi(n,k) = \int_0^{q_n}\varphi(n,k)dk
$$
Then just take the forward difference ($\Delta_na(n) = a(n+1) - a(n)$) on both sides and solve the resulting recurrence for $q_n$:
$$
\varphi(n+1,n+1) + \sum_{k=0}^n\Delta_n\varphi(n,k) = \int_0^{q_{n+1}}\varphi(n+1,k)dk - \int_0^{q_n}\varphi(n,k)dk;\hspace{5mm} \phi(n_0) = \int_0^{q_{n_0}}\varphi(n_0,k)dk
$$
then just use the rules of differentiation under the integral as discussed in the original comments to get:
$$
\frac{d\phi(n)}{dn} = \varphi(n,q_n)\frac{dq_n}{dn} + \int_0^{q_n}\frac{\partial\varphi(n,k)}{\partial n}dk
$$

A simple example to try is $\varphi(n,k) = nk$, for which going through the above procedure yields $q_n = \sqrt{n(n+1)}$, and a quick check confirms that 
$$
\phi(n) = n\int_0^{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}k\hspace{0.7mm}dk = \frac{1}{2}n^2(n+1)
$$
as we would expect. Not sure when this would fail, but the recurrences could get nasty very easily, so in any case might not always be the greatest path to take. Although for separable $\varphi$, $\varphi(n,k) = \nu(n)\mu(k)$, it's not super hard to show that the reucrrence reduces to a much nicer,
$$
\mu(n+1) = \int_{q_n}^{q_{n+1}}\mu(k)dk.
$$
and for which a (redundant) closed form solution is possible for $q_n$: 
$$
q_n = M^{-1}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{dM}{dk}\right)_{k=k+1}\right]
$$$$
M(k) \equiv \int\mu(k)dk
$$